Is there a way in Excel to get from point a to point b
I would like to get from point a to point b as shown below. I thought this was a transpose solution but it doesn't seem to be working the way thought.
Basically, I'm trying to come up with a way to easily collect/manage the data (Point A), then display it a certain way (Point B).
Trying to get ideas on how to solve this the Excel way or a programming way?
Point A

Point B


This question isn't on topic for Stack Overflow. If you're asking how to do this in Excel, then this is a question about using software, see SuperUser. If you're asking how to do this in C#, then you should figure out what steps you'd need to do to transform the data before trying to make the code.

Doing it in Excel and C# are two quite different things.

If you have Excel 365:

=LET(
    serverdata, A2:A5,
    servicesdata, B2:B5,
    servers, UNIQUE(serverdata),
    services, TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(servicesdata)),
    matchMatrix, IF(COUNTIFS(serverdata, servers, servicesdata, services) > 0, "x", ""),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("", services), HSTACK(servers, matchMatrix))
)

serverdata: Reference the server input range
servicesdata: Reference the services input range
servers: Extract unique server names from serverdata
services: Extract unique service names from servicesdata and transpose them to be in a row format.
matchMatrix: Check for each combination of servers and services. If a match is found (i.e., the server offers the service), place an "x"; otherwise, leave the cell blank.
VSTACK: Stack the header row (services) on top of the match matrix starting with a blank cell
HSTACK: Stack the server names on the left of the match matrix.
Populate the x's when there is a match

Any chance you can explain the broad strokes to a 5 year old?

@Rod  - depends how smart they are, please see above.

Doable using the MATCH function:
Say you have your first table on Sheet1.

On sheet2, name your columns exactly as you did:

Now, in cell B2, copy and paste the following:
=IF(SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,$A2,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,B$1,0)))>0,"x","")

Then drag the corner of the cell to fill the entire table.
Breakdown for cell B2
We are trying to see if, for each cell in the column A of Sheet1 matches the content of the row header (server1):
MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,$A2,0)

This evaluates like {1, 1, #N/A, #N/A}.
We then only keep the cells that are numbers by using ISNUMBER (note the placement of the $ sign on $A2 that locks the column but not the row, to keep pointing at the column header when we drag the corner of the cell):
ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,$A2,0))

This evaluates like {TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}.
We do the same for the column header (this time we lock the row B$1 to keep the header), and multiply the two arrays. We end up having {TRUE * TRUE, TRUE * FALSE, FALSE * TRUE, FALSE * FALSE}, which evaluates as {1, 0, 0, 0}.
We sum all of these numbers using SUM, and with a simple IF we can say that if that sum is one or above, then I want to display an x.

It's known as the pivot table:

There are several steps to create the table.
